# Need to enter password for private key twice at git push with gitlab

Tags: gitlab

Whenever I try to push to GIT I need to enter the password for my private key twice which is annoying. Any ideas how to prevent that? Once per push seems enough (ok I'm new to GIT)

Password and ssh definitely work as

```
 ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

with the password results in

> Welcome to GitLab, @myUser!

When I do the push I get the following as log:

```
C:\...\privat\pdm>git push -v origin master 
Pushing to git@gitlab.com:myUser/project.git 
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\...\.ssh\ssl_keys_gmail': 
Enumerating objects: 5, done. 
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done. 
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 246 bytes | 246.00 KiB/s, done. 
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0) 
To gitlab.com:myUser/project.git
    abf2764..c8cb814  master -> master 
updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' 
Pushing to git@gitlab.com:myUser/project.git 
Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\...\.ssh\ssl_keys_gmail': 
To gitlab.com:myUser/project.git
  = [up to date]      master -> master
 updating local tracking ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' Everything up-to-date
```

Answer (score 0):

check out this link: https://help.github.com/en/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git

`git config --global credential.helper cache`# Set git to use the credential memory cache

Comment: Hi Genet, Welcome to Stack Overflow and congrats on your first answer!

"Check out this link" is not considered a detailed answer, as off-site resources often go missing.  

You can read more about writing great answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Didn't work for me unfortunately Still get asked twice for the pwd